# GA solutions for AJAX sites

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, analytics, tealium

the new /solutions/ page is actually a single page with a series of called content via JS, which is to count as pages. These pages are noted by the query parameters triggered by using the filter (middle of the page).

GA is only noticing the /solutions/ page and not the corresponding pages b/c the way that AJAX renders and due to the universal tag living in the static portion of the page. We need to ideally find a route to track all unique pages called and any engagement in those sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **virtual pageview** in Google Analytics to track single page application.

This guide describes how to use `analytics.js` (but you can do it through Google Tag Manager or Tealium too) to measure page activity on sites whose content is loaded dynamically without traditional full page loads:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: Can we do this in Tealium? We don't use GTM.

Comment: Yes, the concept is the same and it is independent of the tagging system used.